RuleMark and Chart BarMark is glitching
I am using SwiftUI Charts framework at this moment to display the last 30 days of data. As you see in code, the x axis each line is new day. The chart and animation is working fine. But the interesting thing is if I remove  .annotation(position: .topLeading, alignment: .topLeading) the chart stays as expected and every thing is good, except that RuleMark() shifts to start or end by dragging it to one side, its like just repeating.
To stop rule mark from repeating I thought I have to fixate x axis so I tried to use .chartXScale(domain: viewModel.chartData.map{ $0.date }.min()!...viewModel.chartData.map{ $0.date }.max()!) and the $0.date is Date() object. But I still got fatal error on unwrapping nil.
Oh yes, so when the annotation is added, the RuleMarker() still shifts from end to start and other way around. And the y axis scales with additional values and makes the BarMark to shrink, and when I release the gesture, it shifts back to normal. And also if the RuleMark() is dragged over the BarMark() it also gets wiggly and bouncy and glitches all together.
My viewModel.chartData consists of 30 days added which could and do contain some days of value 0. Initially when I was adding to barrack parameter width: which messed up the layout a little bit, because the chart was scaling already by 30 bars which most of them had value 0. When I removed width: parameter the chart started to act better and stopped glitching over BarMark() but now is glitching over marks that x axis where y value is 0.
So can some one give me some advice, how can I make RuleMark() to slide from one side to other with annotation and stop chart glitching?
struct StatsView: View {
    @State private var currentSelection = "Last 30 days"
    @State private var currentBar: ChartModel?
    
    @Binding var selectedWallet: String
    @Binding var dismiss: Bool
    
    var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            BackgroundAnimation()
            
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.dismiss.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Done")
                            .foregroundStyle(.yellow)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    })
                }
                .padding()
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12){
                    HStack{
                        Text("Last 30 days")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                        
                        Picker("", selection: $currentSelection) {
                            Text("Last 30 days")
                                .tag("Last 30 days")
                            Text("Last Month")
                                .tag("Last Month")
                            Text("This Year")
                                .tag("This Year")
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(.menu)
                        .padding(.leading, 80)
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(.yellow)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    
                    AnimatedChart()
                }
                .padding()
                .background{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                        .fill(.white.opacity(0.3).shadow(.drop(color: .yellow ,radius: 5)))
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            .padding()
            .onChange(of: currentSelection){
                //TODO: Handle user table change
                //TODO: reanimate graph with true passed in parameter
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func AnimatedChart() -> some View{
        Chart{
            ForEach(viewModel.chartData){ item in
                BarMark(
                    x: .value("Day", item.date, unit: .day),
                    y: .value("Sum", item.animate ? item.count : 0)
                )
                
                if let currentBar, currentBar.id == item.id{
                    RuleMark(x: .value("Day", currentBar.date, unit: .day))
                        .foregroundStyle(.black)
                        .lineStyle(.init(lineWidth: 2, miterLimit: 2, dash: [2], dashPhase: 5))
                        .annotation(position: .topLeading, alignment: .topLeading){
                            AnnotationView(date: currentBar.date, amount: currentBar.count, viewModel: viewModel)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 200)
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(values: .automatic){ value in
                AxisValueLabel() {
                    if let intValue = value.as(Int.self) {
                        Text("\(intValue)EUR")
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .chartXAxis{
            AxisMarks(values: .automatic){ _ in
                AxisValueLabel()
                    .foregroundStyle(.yellow)
            }
        }
        .chartOverlay { proxy in
            GeometryReader{ innerProxy in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged{ value in
                                let location = value.location
                                if let date: Date = proxy.value(atX: location.x){
                                    let calendar = Calendar.current
                                    let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
                                    if let currentTransaction = viewModel.chartData.first(where: { transaction in
                                        calendar.component(.day, from: transaction.date) == day
                                    }){
                                        self.currentBar = currentTransaction
                                    }
                                }
                            }.onEnded({ value in
                                self.currentBar = nil
                            })
                    )
            }
            .onAppear{
                viewModel.fetchLast30DaysTransactions(from: selectedWallet) { transactions in
                    viewModel.aggregateLast30DaysTransactions(from: transactions)
                    animatedingGraph()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private func animatedingGraph(fromChange: Bool = false){
        for (index, _) in viewModel.chartData.enumerated(){
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(index) * (fromChange ? 0.03 : 0.05)){
                withAnimation(fromChange ? .easeIn(duration: 0.8) : .interactiveSpring(response: 0.8, dampingFraction: 0.8, blendDuration: 0.8)){
                    viewModel.chartData[index].animate = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


If some body else stumbles upon this problem, you need to put x axis scaling modifier, and in my case as it did find nil, it was because the network call did not finish before checking min and max dates in array, so it was empty. And there for I added default values of Date() object.
But the y axis extra values and bar mark shrinking I have not yet solved, so let me know.

Ok, I have solved all the problems, just FYI if someday interacts with the same thing I did, scale both axis, and it will do the trick
